# How to Navigate between Forms using Buttons?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012, managed, openform

I am trying to create a simple record storage application but for some idiotic reason C++ is refusing to let me navigate back to my default frmview.h Form, after adding the record.

This is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult Result = MessageBox::Show(this,String::Format("Record Added for user {0}, Add another?", txtstaffname),"title", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo, MessageBoxIcon::Information);

    if(System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes == Result)
        {
            //Do something
        }
            else
                {
                    this->Close;
                    frmview::Show;
                }
```

When I try to execute the debugger I get the following exception:

```
11  IntelliSense: a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class  $PROJECTDIR$\frmnew.h   444 12  Application1
```

Now the form that I am trying to go back to is the View Records Form which is also used to go the the current Add Records (frmnew.h) Form and I have included the following headers on both Forms:

frmview.h (View Records):

```
#include "frmadd.h"
#include "frmedit.h"
```

frmadd.h (Add Records):

```
#include "frmview.h"
```

My computer system is running Windows 8.1 and I have Visual Studio 2012 installed (.NET 4.5)

If it were up to me I would use C# or VB.NET but as part of our assignment we have to use C++.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problems with **double inclusion**.
You are including "frmadd.h" which will include "frmview.h" and so on endlessly.

If you need to save some data from second form to the first one, you can use `property` and navigate safely through the forms.
Hope this helps.

Ps.: I think `Show` method needs brackets: `Show()`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code to ascertain the problem I have had to assume a lot, hence the multi-solution answer:

If multiple inclusion is the problem then a pre-processor directive to only define/include if not previously included should solve the problem:
wrap the whole contents on your .h files in

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HEADERFILENAMEHERE_H
#define HEADERFILENAMEHERE_H
//.....
original header file contents here
//.....
#endif
```

However based on the error you have output, I think the syntax you are using is wrong:
looks like you need to call

```
frmview->Show(this);
```

instead of

```
frmview::Show;
```

Another possibility is that you may need to restructure your code to be more inline with the following:

```
//SecondForm.cpp

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "FirstForm.h"
#include "SecondForm.h"

System::Void CppWinform::SecondForm::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
 FirstForm^ firstForm = gcnew FirstForm();
 firstForm->Show();
 this->Hide();
}

System::Void CppWinform::FirstForm::button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 SecondForm^ secondForm = gcnew SecondForm();
 secondForm->Show();
 this->Hide();               
}
```

Let me know how you get on, and if you need any more info I will be happy to help:)